# Should notify data-set-change out side of adapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm doing notifying data-set-change inside of `Adapter`.

like,

```
fun setItems(items: MutableList<IMyModel>) {
    list = items
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun updateItems(pos: Int: item: IMyModel) {
    list[pos] = item
    notifyItemChanged(pos)
}
```

But in many tutorials, I can see they do outside of the `Adapter`.

```
adapter.setItems(items)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

So I just wondered **if there is any reason I should notify that outside of `Adapter`?** like a bad practice?

Comment: I think it does not make any difference as the `same method is being called`, just the difference is in activity it is called through the adapters instance.

Comment: no it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you should call notify directly after changing the dataset, no matter in which class that change occurs.